# How to set up wine on Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: wine

How do I run windows applications on ubuntu using updated wine. What type of file do I have to open with wine to run the apps. Is Playonlinux necessary for using wine?

Comment: You wont get an answer here. setting up wine correctly is very much related to what you want to run in wine. 2nd:POL is not needed but adds preset config files for wine for loads and loads of programs. Please consider using virtualbox. far less hassle to set up and you then also have less hassle installing windows software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wine is just a software compatibility layer. This means that it implements functions which are not available on Linux/Mac. You can use it as-is, although it may be difficult for you, since its user interface is oriented to more experienced users.

PlayOnLinux makes using Windows software on Linux easier. It contains scripts for setting up specific applications and also pair them with Wine version on which they run best.

It depends which task you are trying to complete. PlayOnLinux fits most of basic tasks.